# TypeScript: default is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, import, module, export, typescript-typings

In my TypeScript project I want to use a Node.js module called "[pure-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-uuid)".

With plain JavaScript, "pure-uuid" can be used as follows:

```
const UUID = require('pure-uuid')
const id = new UUID(4).format();
```

I translated the code into TypeScript:

```
import UUID from 'pure-uuid';
const id:string = new UUID(4).format();
```

When I compile the code, the following is being generated:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var pure_uuid_1 = require("pure-uuid");
var id = new pure_uuid_1.default(4).format();
```

Unfortunately TypeScript adds a `.default` to the "pure-uuid" reference, which makes the code fail on execution:

```
TypeError: pure_uuid_1.default is not a constructor
```

I think the wrong compilation is caused by a mistake in the TypeScript definition file (which has been manually written):

```
interface UUID {
    /*  making  */
    make(version: number, ...params: any[]): UUID;

    /*  parsing  */
    parse(str: string): UUID;

    /*  formatting  */
    format(type?: string): string;

    /*  formatting (alias)  */
    tostring(type?: string): string;

    /*  importing  */
    import(arr: number[]): UUID;

    /*  exporting  */
    export(): number[];

    /*  byte-wise comparison  */
    compare(other: UUID): boolean;
}

export interface UUIDConstructor {
  /*  default construction  */
  new(): UUID;

  /*  parsing construction  */
  new(uuid: string): UUID;

  /*  making construction  */
  new(version: number): UUID;
  new(version: number, ns: string, data: string): UUID;
}

declare var UUID: UUIDConstructor;
export default UUID;
```

What's the correct way of exporting the "pure-uuid" module?

Comment: You can not declare a constructor declaration in an interface.

Comment: Try: `export = UUID;`

Comment: @Paleo, using `export = UUID;` shows `error TS2693: 'UUID' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` when writing `new UUID(4).format()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `export =`:

```
interface UUID {
  // ...
}

interface UUIDConstructor {
  /*  default construction  */
  new(): UUID;
  // ...
}

declare var tmp: UUIDConstructor;
export = tmp;
```

See also: [The documentation on `export =`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).

Then, the following code:

```
const UUID = require('pure-uuid')
```

… must be translated with:

```
import UUID = require('pure-uuid');
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If I do that, than I am receiving the following error: `error TS1192: Module '"../node_modules/pure-uuid/uuid"' has no default export.`.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer I edited. The equivalent to `const UUID = require ...` is `import * as UUID from ...`.

Comment: I tried switching `const` to `import` but TS 3.4 complained. What worked was `const package = require("package").default;`

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare a constructor declaration in an interface.

Typescript is a superset of JavaScript, it includes JavaScript. Therefore, your TypeScript should be simply this:

```
const UUID = require('pure-uuid');
const id = new UUID(4).format();
```

Comment: When using `const UUID = require('pure-uuid');` I am losing the benefit of having types and auto completion based on types from `UUID`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer here, because the error in this question may pop up
with many JavaScript libraries and this is one of the places where people may come looking. The error message was very confusing to me at first. (I encountered this with the AWS SDK.)

So I think the import that you are looking for is of this format:

```
import * as UUID from 'pure-uuid'
```

This imports everything from `pure-uuid` and puts it in the namespace `UUID`.

Note, that starting from `pure-script` version 1.4 the simpler import works as expected:

```
import UIID from 'pure-uuid'
```

The error `TypeError: foo_bar_1.default is not a constructor` is caused by the module being imported not providing the wanted definitions in its "default export".

See the [TypeScript documentation on modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). The [Mozilla documentation on Javascript import-statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) may be easier to skim quickly.
The syntax is the same in both languages AFAIK. (The TypeScript documentation states the following "Starting with ECMAScript 2015, JavaScript has a concept of modules. TypeScript shares this concept.")